# How can I fix this topology problem?

Tags: topology

How can I fix this topology issue? It looks like it's because the vertexes are not aligned on the plane?[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: looks like overlapping faces/vertices. share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Definitely overlapping or duplicate geometry, I'd say.

Comment: Try `Flatten` in the `Loop Tools` addon